# Android SDK 4.0 Reading Camera Preview Frames only in a Service without Activity

Tags: android, camera

I'm working on a computer-vision application that uses rear camera.

I'm using Android SDK for 4.0 (API 14)

I spent a few days trying to get preview frame in realtime, through onPreviewFrame, but have failed so far.

I think that the camera actually invoke preview callback when the previewDisplay is actually rendered in an activity.

But I have to capture camera images only in a service, without activity.

Any suggestions for this?

I've already tried making dummy surfaceView but it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest trying `Service.startActivity(intent)`

Services don't have a UI, you need an Activity for that. But you can start an Activity from your Service.

Also, I don't think you can take a picture without the user's knowledge.